Problem creating a SMILES object that can then be used to create a MOL object
I would like to convert these complexes,tBudippf, into SMILES objects and then create MOL objects from these SMILES. However, when I generate the SMILES associated with these complexes, I am unable to create MOL objects afterward.
I suspect the SMILES notation is incorrect, but I cannot identify the correct SMILES.
This is one my SMILE notation : "FC(C=CC=C1)=C1C2=NN=CO2.IC1=CC=C(OC)C=C1.C(=O)([O-])[O-].[Cs+].[Cs+].C1COCCO1.[Cu+].[I-].CC(C)(C)[C-]1([CH]2=C34P(C5CCCCC5)C6CCCCC6)[CH]7=[CH]3[Fe+2]7189%10%1124[CH]%12=C([CH]9=[CH]%10[C-]%12%11C(C)(C)C)8P(C%13CCCCC%13)C%14CCCCC%14.FC1=C(C2=NN=C(C3=CC=C(OC)C=C3)O2)C=CC=C1"
I tried adding sanitize=False when using Chem.MolFromSmiles, and this displayed the correct complex, but with sanitization, I can't create a MOL object. I attempted to draw my complex in Chemcraft to generate a SMILES, but despite trying various types of drawings, I still can’t succeed.
Do you have a solution to create a SMILES representation for this complex and then create a MOL from it?
complexe

Any code ??? Fies molfromsmiles returns None , any error ?? See https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/763a70b70718187ab28197dedd2ffa8392c8fff8

This what I get from your input:
import rdkit

print('\n-------------------------------')

print('\n rdkit Version : ', rdkit.__version__)

print('\n-------------------------------')


from rdkit import Chem

from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole

from rdkit.Chem import Draw


mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles("FC(C=CC=C1)=C1C2=NN=CO2.IC1=CC=C(OC)C=C1.C(=O)([O-])[O-].[Cs+].[Cs+].C1COCCO1.[Cu+].[I-].CC(C)(C)[C-]1([CH]2=C34P(C5CCCCC5)C6CCCCC6)[CH]7=[CH]3[Fe+2]7189%10%1124[CH]%12=C([CH]9=[CH]%10[C-]%12%11C(C)(C)C)8P(C%13CCCCC%13)C%14CCCCC%14.FC1=C(C2=NN=C(C3=CC=C(OC)C=C3)O2)C=CC=C1",
                         
                         # sanitize = False)
                         
                         sanitize = True)

Draw.ShowMol(mol)

Output :
File ".../.../.../.../rdkit/Chem/Draw/__init__.py", line 233, in MolToImage
    raise ValueError('Null molecule provided')

ValueError: Null molecule provided

with :
sanitize = False

Output :

this is from Smi2DepictWeb :

Now the Question is I hope more complete.
from RDKit Frequently Asked Questions  :

When you read in a molecule the RDKit, by default, does a lot of preprocessing - called sanitization - to perceive chemistry and detect errors. The documentation has a detailed description of this.
One of the checks which is performed by default is to make sure that all of the atoms in the molecule have valence states which make chemical sense. If there's an atom with a chemically unreasonable valence state (like the four-coordinate neutral N in the example above), then an error is reported and the molecule is rejected

Now I get the question probably belongs to
Chemistry Stack Exchange ; Matter Modeling 
Guess could be something related to Fe , but not an expert
Google is your friend :
adding lines:
problems = Chem.DetectChemistryProblems(mol)
for p in problems:
    print(p.Message())

from Handling SMILES with metal ions in RDKit
I get more interesting output:
Explicit valence for atom # 39 C, 5, is greater than permitted
Explicit valence for atom # 40 C, 5, is greater than permitted
Explicit valence for atom # 41 C, 5, is greater than permitted
Explicit valence for atom # 55 C, 5, is greater than permitted
Explicit valence for atom # 56 C, 5, is greater than permitted
Explicit valence for atom # 58 C, 5, is greater than permitted
Explicit valence for atom # 59 C, 5, is greater than permitted
Explicit valence for atom # 60 C, 5, is greater than permitted
Explicit valence for atom # 61 C, 5, is greater than permitted
Explicit valence for atom # 62 C, 5, is greater than permitted

So far for your:

molecule
I got with SMILES: "[C]12=[C]3[Fe]4567892([C]1[C]4=[C]35P(C(C)C)C(C)C)[C]1=[C]6([C]7=[C]8[C]91)P(C(C)C)C(C)C" :

Can't translate mol to 3D mol to get a better look at the result
because of a AtomValenceException: Explicit valence for atom # 4 C, 5, is greater than permitted
Also :
"[Fe+2]12345678([C]9=[C]1[C]2=[C]3[C]49)[C]1=[C]5[C]6=[C]7[C]81"

wil give rise to:
[23:00:38] UFFTYPER: Unrecognized hybridization for atom: 0
[23:00:38] UFFTYPER: Unrecognized atom type: Fe+2 (0)


Yep, don't try to use SMILES to represent the structures of organometallic compounds.

tell to NCBI people C1=CC2=NC1=CC3=NC(=CC4=NC(=CC5=NC(=C2)C=C5)C=C4)C=C3.[Fe+3] ;  https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/9928995
